# Merge two unique excel spreadsheets, remove one spreadsheet when needed

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet

Hopefully I can explain this decently.

I am attempting to merge two unique excel spreadsheets, with some of the same data, into one spreadsheet.  When needed I would like to remove the data from the incoming spreadsheet.  I am doing this as it would make it easier to edit one "like" spreadsheet, rather then keep and update two copies.  I do not want to hide the incoming data, I NEED to completely remove it when needed.

Thanks!

Comment: if this helps anyone I found a useful program called [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the spreadsheets look like and what, exactly, you mean by *merge*.

If, for example, the two worksheets contain a table each, then you could copy/append one table to the bottom of the other and use Excel's `Remove Duplicates` feature (on the Data tab) to delete rows.

The duplicates can be identified either by a single code-number column, all of the columns (meaning that the entire row is duplicated) or a selection of columns. Be aware that it is the first duplicated row that is kept, the subsequent duplicates will be removed.

If, on the other hand, you want to find values in the rows of one of the worksheets, based on a code number contained in a column of the other worksheet, and insert them into specific cells, then this requires more effort, perhaps with the help of the VLOOKUP function (or similar).